# Regex: match last and second-last character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to wrap the two last characters in a string in a separate `<span>`:

```
-1:23 // This is what I have
-1:<span>2</span><span>3</span> // This is what I want
```

The following matches the last character – but how can I make it match the second last as well?

```
str.replace(/(.$)/, "<span>$1</span>");
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
.replace(/.(?=.?$)/g, "<span>$&</span>")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c29u0q/1)

If these must be digits, replace `.` with `\d`:

```
.replace(/\d(?=\d?$)/g, "<span>$&</span>")
```

The pattern matches

- `\d` - a digit
- `(?=\d?$)` - that is followed with an end of string or a digit and end of string.

The `$&` is a replacement backreference that references the whole match value from the string replacement pattern.

JS demo:

```js
console.log("-1:23".replace(/.(?=.?$)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
console.log("-1:23".replace(/\d(?=\d?$)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
```

Now, to make it more dynamic, you may use a **limiting (range/interval) quantifier**:

```js
function wrap_chars(text, num_chars) {
  var reg = new RegExp(".(?=.{0," + (num_chars-1) + "}$)", "g");
  return text.replace(reg, "<span>$&</span>");
}
console.log(wrap_chars("-1:23", 1)); // wrap one char at the end with span
console.log(wrap_chars("-1:23", 2)); // wrap two chars at the end with span
```

Comment: Why not use explicit quantifiers? `.{2}$` should achieve the same effect, right?

Comment: @Vogel612 The `.{2}$` pattern will yield [`-1:<span>23</span>`](https://regex101.com/r/c29u0q/2). That was my first thought, that is why I closed the question. When I realized it is not the case, I reopened. I also added a dynamoc solution to wrap N chars at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another group before the last one, which also matches a single character (`(.)`), then wrap each of them using references (`$1` and `$2`):

```js
var str = '-1:23'.replace(/(.)(.)$/, '<span>$1</span><span>$2</span>')
console.log(str);
```